# detecting changes in a live xml feed, parsing and then sending to mysql using php

Tags: php, xml-parsing, websocket, polling

What would be the best way to listen out for changes in a live xml feed, parse the file and then insert into a mysql database. At the moment I'm thinking about polling the xml file using ajax and jquery's settimeout or setinterval function.

I've also researched long-polling techniques, which would probably reduce the amount of calls I'm making.

Would I be able to use websockets for this sort of thing and are they efficient with php as the back-end?

Answer (score 0):

I'd set up a `setInterval` to query the DB and XML then compare, if there's a difference then update.

---

```
var time = 50000, //desired update time in milliseconds 
    checkData = setInterval(function(){
var current = queryDB(), //function returns db data in string format 
    live = getLive();    //function gets xml then returns in string format

if (current != live) { updateDB(); }

}, time);
```

This should give you an idea.

Comment: pretty good idea, so query both in one step? How would I go about implementing this

Comment: Set up two functions, one to get the data from the DB and another to get the XML. Then convert both sets of data to strings. From there it just takes an if statement to compare the two. If different, update.

Comment: would multiple setinterval functions be harsh on cpu

Comment: `setInterval` is javascript, meaning that it's only called when someone loads the page. If you want it to constantly update without users viewing page you'd have to set up a `Cron`.

Comment: yeah if it's in the header.php of each page though it will load, right? With a cron I would be limited to intervals of 1min+

Comment: In the header yes. A `Cron`-job is when the physical server loads the page. Think Windows Task Scheduler, it's just the Linux version.

Comment: Yeah I know what a Cron job is but it would only allow me to update the page at a minimum of 1min per interval

Comment: Yes. Either way, you can. Though it would be less taxing on the server if you use `setInterval`

Answer (score 0):

setInterval would be an easier less obtrusive solution. You may find an added layer of complexity when trying to use websockets.

Although if you like you could checkout http://socket.io/ which provides a cross browser approach to websockets is pretty cool.

I would say making a decision on this depends on the frequency of the intervals and the necessity to load data with javascript (after a page load).

Comment: I would need intervals at around 30 seconds. I've checked out socket.io but don't you need to run it with node.js